# Twitter bootstrap Filter only works when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to set the filter value of a table by using Javascript. The problem i have is that when im typing in the value in the filter field everything works correctly but when im doing something like :

```
$("input[type=text]").val("boe");
```

The "boe" is set in the field but the filter is not responding on the input. This is probably something stupid that the filter only reacts on keyup. I am using Twitter bootstrap data tables library from : [Twitter boostrap datatable](http://www.sourcecodester.com/javajavascript/5062/twitter-bootstrap-data-table.html)

Any advice is welcome! And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this after your line:

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup();
```

or even better as @h2ooooooo suggested in the comment:

```
$("input[type=text]").val("boe").keyup();
```

Comment: @user2054820 Like any jQuery, you can also just chain it: `$("input[type=text]").val("boe").keyup();`.